# Facebook new popup - Wants to use "facebook.com" to sign in

Tags: facebook

I was using facebook to sign into my app. All was good. I updated my NPM and now I am getting a strange popup saying.

```
"appName" Wants to Use "facebook.com" 
to Sign In This allows the app and website 
to  share information about you.
```

This was not there a few months ago. I feel its overkill since when you say Continue it sends you to another page asking the same question.

Anyone have the same issue.

Ionic dev

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is facebook new api expected action. Non-issue.

Mark this as closed.

Thanks
Phil